# Error Code: 1100. Table 'product_group' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql

I'm a little confused here. As far as I can see the product_group table is being locked.

If I remove the LOCK section the code executes and returns the data as expected.

Hopefully someone can spot an obvious mistake!

Also I see that the error message is referring to "product_group" as I thought it would refer to "1_product_group" unless I'm mistaken.

Not sure what other information I can provide here.

```
LOCK TABLE 
1_products p READ,
1_packages g READ,
1_stock READ,
1_products_variants READ,
1_products_variants_plu READ,
1_product_group product_group READ,
1_product_group_eit READ,
1_products_packages_media a READ,
1_related r READ,
1_makes m READ,
1_offer_items i READ,
1_url_key url_key READ,
1_headline_group h READ,
supplier_records READ,
addresses READ;

SELECT 
    p.id,
    plu_code,
    p.make,
    model,
    price_each,
    price_pair,
    price_each_inc,
    price_pair_inc,
    rrp,
    rrp_inc,
    cover_type,
    cover_value_each,
    cover_value_pair,
    cover_value_each_inc,
    cover_value_pair_inc,
    cost,
    vat_rate,
    fk_group_id,
    (SELECT 
            fk_group_id
        FROM
            1_product_group product_group
        WHERE
            product_group.id = p.fk_group_id),
    (SELECT 
            position
        FROM
            1_product_group product_group
        WHERE
            product_group.id = p.fk_group_id),
    fk_web_groups,
    fk_condition_id,
    warranty,
    added,
    modified,
    discontinued,
    web_model,
    url_key.url,
    supp_code,
    supp_ref,
    barcode,
    special,
    web_vis_each,
    web_vis_pair,
    web_newitem,
    web_newitem_actioned,
    allow_sale,
    shop_feed,
    p.is_active,
    p.active_from,
    p.active_to,
    mpn,
    no_gtin,
    gtin,
    aka,
    headings,
    p.description,
    model_number,
    spec,
    txt_bul,
    txt_head,
    weight,
    width,
    depth,
    height,
    prod_speech,
    ovr_google_taxonomy,
    pos_text,
    search_name,
    points_mult,
    iff_max_term,
    fk_headlines_id,
    headline,
    each_cap,
    pair_cap,
    no_pack,
    rev_ent,
    title,
    meta_key,
    meta_des,
    default_fk_products_packages_media_id,
    serial_scan,
    p.sn,
    m.id,
    m.speech,
    h.id,
    h.description,
    (SELECT 
            company
        FROM
            addresses
        WHERE
            id = (SELECT 
                    fk_addresses_id
                FROM
                    supplier_records
                WHERE
                    supp_number = p.supp_code))
FROM
    1_products p
        LEFT JOIN
    1_makes m ON p.make = m.make
        LEFT JOIN
    1_headline_group h ON p.fk_headlines_id = h.id
        LEFT JOIN
    1_url_key url_key ON url_type = 1 AND fk_id = p.id
WHERE
    p.id = 11527;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I will have to modify with a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each alias must be unique over the whole query. Whereas the alias mentioned is used twice.

```
LOCK TABLE 
1_products p READ,
1_packages g READ,
1_stock READ,
1_products_variants READ,
1_products_variants_plu READ,
1_product_group product_group READ,
/* fix part 1 */
1_product_group product_group_1 READ,
/* end fix */
1_product_group_eit READ,
1_products_packages_media a READ,
1_related r READ,
1_makes m READ,
1_offer_items i READ,
1_url_key url_key READ,
1_headline_group h READ,
supplier_records READ,
addresses READ;

SELECT 
    p.id,
    plu_code,
    p.make,
    model,
    price_each,
    price_pair,
    price_each_inc,
    price_pair_inc,
    rrp,
    rrp_inc,
    cover_type,
    cover_value_each,
    cover_value_pair,
    cover_value_each_inc,
    cover_value_pair_inc,
    cost,
    vat_rate,
    fk_group_id,
    (SELECT 
            fk_group_id
        FROM
            1_product_group product_group
        WHERE
            product_group.id = p.fk_group_id),
    (SELECT 
            position
        FROM
/* fix part 2 */
            1_product_group product_group_1
        WHERE
            product_group_1.id = p.fk_group_id),
/* end fix */
    fk_web_groups,
    fk_condition_id,
    warranty,
    added,
    modified,
    discontinued,
    web_model,
    url_key.url,
    supp_code,
    supp_ref,
    barcode,
    special,
    web_vis_each,
    web_vis_pair,
    web_newitem,
    web_newitem_actioned,
    allow_sale,
    shop_feed,
    p.is_active,
    p.active_from,
    p.active_to,
    mpn,
    no_gtin,
    gtin,
    aka,
    headings,
    p.description,
    model_number,
    spec,
    txt_bul,
    txt_head,
    weight,
    width,
    depth,
    height,
    prod_speech,
    ovr_google_taxonomy,
    pos_text,
    search_name,
    points_mult,
    iff_max_term,
    fk_headlines_id,
    headline,
    each_cap,
    pair_cap,
    no_pack,
    rev_ent,
    title,
    meta_key,
    meta_des,
    default_fk_products_packages_media_id,
    serial_scan,
    p.sn,
    m.id,
    m.speech,
    h.id,
    h.description,
    (SELECT 
            company
        FROM
            addresses
        WHERE
            id = (SELECT 
                    fk_addresses_id
                FROM
                    supplier_records
                WHERE
                    supp_number = p.supp_code))
FROM
    1_products p
        LEFT JOIN
    1_makes m ON p.make = m.make
        LEFT JOIN
    1_headline_group h ON p.fk_headlines_id = h.id
        LEFT JOIN
    1_url_key url_key ON url_type = 1 AND fk_id = p.id
WHERE
    p.id = 11527;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```